Movie featuring a humanoid killer robot with a metal body and the head of a bald African-American man
It is about a humanoid robot with an all-metal body, except for the head. His head was that of a bald African-American man and instead of eyes he had something silvery metallic inlaid. At one point in the film, he kills a blond guy with a beard or long hair and cuts off his head with a sword to use his body to chase other guys in some kind of laboratory.
I remember that I saw that movie on television in 2001 and I found it again in 2011, but I lost the name.
It's not:

Saturn 3 (1980)
Hardware (1990)
Death Machine (1994)
Moontrap (1988)


Not Virus?

Plus this one.

How does he use the body to chase the other people? Does he transplant his head? Rig it to run into the room? Throw it at them?

My first impulse was the 1996 film Solo, but his body and face look pretty human throughout most of the film.

My first impulse was Cyborg from Teen Titans, but I'm fairly sure that's not who the OP is thinking of.  :-)

I know this movie!  An AI from a video game takes over a motion capture suit that's basically a robot.  It kills the black game dev first and uses parts of him to "complete" its body.  Give me time to track down the name...

How to Make a Monster from 2001?
From Wikipedia:

Following a disastrous video game test, Clayton Software fires the
development team and replaces them with weapons expert Hardcore, game
artificial intelligence designer Sol, and sound effects creator Bug.
Company CEO Faye Clayton promises $1 million to whoever makes the
scariest game, sparking a rivalry amongst the trio. Three weeks later,
the programmers try out their game and computer network-integrated
motion capture suit with help from company intern Laura Wheeler.
However, lightning strikes the building, causing a blackout and wiping
their data. Knowing someone has to stay overnight to monitor the
backup, the four use the game to decide. Ultimately, Sol is chosen to
stay behind.
After he inserts his new AI chip into the company mainframe, the suit
activates and kills Sol. The following morning, Hardcore and Bug find
Sol's body merged to the suit and the backup CD gone. The former
attempts to review the security camera's footage, but is attacked by
the suit, which decapitates him so it can take his body and weapons to
better resemble one of the game's monsters.

The entire NSFW film is on YouTube.




Fair warning, the linked film has female upper body nudity, so you may not want to watch it at work or in a public area.

Arguably, the violence should count too... but nudity seems to be more of an issue.

Dang, you beat me to it.
